# Navmenu items doesn't change unless it's refreshed it.

Tags: asp.net, angular, web, navbar

I have an angular app that has authentication system. Inside the navmenu, I have login, logout and a text that displays username. It works just fine, however, when the user logged in, I still see the same navbar. login should be gone and logout along with username text should be there. But it's not. They are there only when user refreshes the page. I don't know what I'm missing.

Here is my `navmenu.component.html`

```
<li *ngIf="!currentUser"><a [routerLink]="['/login']"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
<li *ngIf="currentUser"><a (click)="logout()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
<li *ngIf="currentUser"><a><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> {{ currentUser.firstName }} {{ currentUser.lastName }}</a></li>
```

And here is my `navmenu.component.ts` code:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { User } from './../../models/user';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './../../services/auth.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'nav-menu',
    templateUrl: './navmenu.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./navmenu.component.css']
})
export class NavMenuComponent implements OnInit {
    currentUser: User;

ngOnInit() {
    this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') || '');
}


constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {  }


   logout() {
      this.authService.logout();
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
   }
}
```

Lastly, here is my `app.component.html` file looks like:

```
<nav-menu></nav-menu>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: The fngOnInit method is executed only once. How do you suppose that the NavMenuComponent is notified that the user has loged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ngOnInit will be called only once, so I suggest to do the following:

**auth.service.ts**

```
// Your code here
authStateChanged: Subject<AuthState> = new Subject<AuthState>();
// Your code here
```

**auth-state.enum.ts**

```
export enum AuthState {
    Authorized,
    Unauthorized
}
```

**component.ts**

Leave everything as is, just change ngOnInit slightly.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.authStateChanged.subscribe(
        authState => { this.refreshCurrentUser(); }
    )
}

refreshCurrentUser() {
    this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser') || '');
}
```

You can add more login to check authState, this is just basic example that will work in your case.

Now inside your **auth.service** when you do logon, on success simply do:

```
this.authStateChange.next(AuthState.Authorized);
```

Comment: This time, when logon, I see logout and text that displays username. However, when the page is refreshed, it gets back to the login only status. I also, added `this.authStateChanged.next(AuthState.Unauthorized);` to my logput function but this time nothing happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `BehaviorSubject` that checks if there is a user in `localStorage` and also emits changes in the status.

Service:

```
private user = new BehaviorSubject<any>(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')))
public user$ = this.user.asObservable();

setUser(user) {
  localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user))
  this.user.next(true)
}
```

we call `setUser()` when the status changes. And every subscriber get's the status.

Login:

```
login() {
  this.authService.setUser({user: 'Admin'});
}
```

and each component that you want to listen to, add this to constructor:

```
constructor(private authService: Service) {  
  authService.user$.subscribe(val => {
    this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'))
  })
}
```

and then of course when you want to log out user, do...

```
logout() {
  this.authService.setUser(null)
}
```